# Host gitlab server locally, have 502

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

```
run: alertmanager: (pid 398260) 20s; run: log: (pid 282970) 26999s
run: gitaly: (pid 398271) 19s; run: log: (pid 281998) 27111s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 398289) 19s; run: log: (pid 282760) 27017s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 398299) 18s; run: log: (pid 282586) 27040s
run: grafana: (pid 398308) 18s; run: log: (pid 283326) 26937s
run: logrotate: (pid 398321) 18s; run: log: (pid 282680) 27027s
run: nginx: (pid 398331) 17s; run: log: (pid 282650) 27033s
run: node-exporter: (pid 398417) 17s; run: log: (pid 282735) 27021s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 398424) 16s; run: log: (pid 283009) 26993s
run: postgresql: (pid 398434) 16s; run: log: (pid 282173) 27103s
run: prometheus: (pid 398444) 15s; run: log: (pid 282824) 27005s
run: puma: (pid 398457) 15s; run: log: (pid 282514) 27052s
run: redis: (pid 398462) 14s; run: log: (pid 281943) 27117s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 398471) 14s; run: log: (pid 282788) 27011s
run: sidekiq: (pid 398505) 9s; run: log: (pid 282548) 27046s
```

[Have 502 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGrsg.png)

I have tried to set unicorn, puma and workhorse's port but nothing works after reconfigure and restart. Really no idea what's going on here. The seconds seem like abnormally large.

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/prometheus/current <==
2021-03-07_05:58:32.64985 level=info ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.649Z caller=main.go:735 msg="TSDB started"
2021-03-07_05:58:32.64992 level=info ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.649Z caller=main.go:861 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/var/opt/
metheus/prometheus.yml
2021-03-07_05:58:32.65283 level=error ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.652Z caller=manager.go:314 component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Canno
ervice discovery" err="unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kub
/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes
2021-03-07_05:58:32.65289 level=error ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.652Z caller=manager.go:314 component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Canno
ervice discovery" err="unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kub
/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes
2021-03-07_05:58:32.65303 level=error ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.653Z caller=manager.go:314 component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Canno
ervice discovery" err="unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kub
/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes
2021-03-07_05:58:32.66197 level=info ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.661Z caller=main.go:892 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filen
pt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml totalDuration=12.051953ms remote_storage=3.382µs web_handler=668ns query_engine=1.758µs scrape=153.
pe_sd=919.213µs notify=84.184µs notify_sd=157.198µs rules=8.260372ms
2021-03-07_05:58:32.66200 level=info ts=2021-03-07T05:58:32.661Z caller=main.go:684 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
2021-03-07_05:58:37.66299 level=error ts=2021-03-07T05:58:37.662Z caller=manager.go:188 component="scrape manager" msg="error creating
 pool" err="error creating HTTP client: unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /va
ets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" scrape_pool=kubernetes-nodes
2021-03-07_05:58:37.66302 level=error ts=2021-03-07T05:58:37.662Z caller=manager.go:188 component="scrape manager" msg="error creating
 pool" err="error creating HTTP client: unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /va
ets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" scrape_pool=kubernetes-pods
2021-03-07_05:58:37.66303 level=error ts=2021-03-07T05:58:37.662Z caller=manager.go:188 component="scrape manager" msg="error creating
 pool" err="error creating HTTP client: unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /va
ets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" scrape_pool=kubernetes-cadvisor

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitaly/current <==
{"address":"/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/internal.sock","level":"info","msg":"listening at unix address","time":"2021-03-07T
95Z"}
{"address":"localhost:9236","level":"info","msg":"starting prometheus listener","time":"2021-03-07T05:58:28.999Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"starting RSS monitor","supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.0","supervisor.rss_threshold":209715200,"time":"2021-03-07T
00Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.0  \u003cni
\u003cnil\u003e}. Err: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby
t: connection refused\". Reconnecting...","pid":406772,"system":"system","time":"2021-03-07T05:58:29.000Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"spawned","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/serv
-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","406772","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.0"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.0","supervisor.pid":40
":"2021-03-07T05:58:29.001Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"spawned","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/serv
-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","406772","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.1"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.1","supervisor.pid":40
":"2021-03-07T05:58:29.002Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"starting RSS monitor","supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.1","supervisor.rss_threshold":209715200,"time":"2021-03-07T
03Z"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.1  \u003cni
\u003cnil\u003e}. Err: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby
t: connection refused\". Reconnecting...","pid":406772,"system":"system","time":"2021-03-07T05:58:29.004Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"PID 406790 BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/Gemfile","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","
d","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","406772","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_socket
,"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.1","time":"2021-03-07T05:58:29.287Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"PID 406789 BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/Gemfile","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","
d","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","406772","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_socket
,"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.0","time":"2021-03-07T05:58:29.296Z"}
```